# How to use one view by two different users in django?

Tags: django, url, view, model, request

I have a custom user model as below:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = EmailField(verbose_name='email address', max_length=255, unique=True, )
    first_name = CharField(verbose_name='First Name', max_length=30, null=True, )
    middle_name = CharField(verbose_name='Middle Name', max_length=30, null=True, blank=True, )
    last_name = CharField(verbose_name='Last Name', max_length=30, null=True, )
    phone_number = CharField(verbose_name='Phone Number', max_length=30, null=True, )
    is_partner = BooleanField(default=False, )
    is_student = BooleanField(default=False, )

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = CustomUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

As shown above, a user can be a student or can be a partner, who will be in charge of a few students and have access to their assets.
The partner model is as below:

```
class Partner(Model):
    user = OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=CASCADE)
    partner_name = CharField(max_length=100, )
```

The student model is as below:

```
class Student(Model):
    user = OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=CASCADE)
    student_name = CharField(max_length=100, )
    partner = ForeignKey(Partner, on_delete=SET_NULL, null=True)
```

As shown, in the Student model, partner can be null. The reason is that a student can either directly enroll in the system without having a partner or he/she can be enrolled by a partner. A student might even specify a partner that is optional when he/she is enrolling.

I have a student view and url pattern:

```
path('student_profile/', student_profile, name='student_profile')

def student_profile(request):
    user = request.user
    student = get_object_or_404(Student, user=user)
    return HttpResponse('The student will do AAAAAA')
```

I have a url pattern and partner view:

```
path('partner_profile/', partner_profile, name='partner_profile')


def partner_profile(request):
    user = request.user
    partner = get_object_or_404(Partner, user=user)
    return HttpResponse('The partner will do some stuff such as updating his/her profile')
```

there is this url pattern and view that allowes a partner to see his/her list of student:

```
path('partners/<int:partner_pk>/students/', partner_students, name='partner_students')

def partner_students(request):
    template_name = 'partners/partner_students.html'
    context = {}
    partner = get_object_or_404(Partner, user=request.user)
    partner_students = Student.objects.filter(partner=partner)
    context.update({'partner_students': partner_students})
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

in template, I can have this url path:

```
path('students/<int:student_pk>/', partner_student_profile, name='partner_student_profile')


{% for student in partner_students %}
   <a href="{% url 'partner_student_profile' student_pk=student.pk %}">student.pk</a>
{% endfor %}
```

What I need is that somehow, instead of rewriting a view to do some stuff with the student profile, I use the one that is already written.
I want to use this:

```
def student_profile(request):
    user = request.user
    student = get_object_or_404(Student, user=user)
    return HttpResponse('The student will do some stuff such as updating his/her profile')
```

I do not want to write this:

```
def partner_student_profile(request, student_pk):
    student = Student.objects.get(pk=student_pk)
    return HttpResponse('The partner will do AAAAAA for his/her student')
```

I want to reuse the already written "student_profile" view

Answer (score 0):

Have a url like this.

```
path('profile/<str:profile_type>/<int:pk>', profile_view, name='profile_view')
```

Now create a view to map to this url.

```
def profile_view(request, profile_type: str, pk: int):
    user = request.user
    if profile_type == 'partner':
        """
        do something
        """
        template_name = 'partner_handler.html'
        context = dict()
    elif profile_type == 'student':
        """
        do something
        """
        template_name = 'student_handler.html'
        context = dict()
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

So basically, you are using two url path parameters to check what type of profile you want to work with, in your case it's going to be a student or partner. Depending on the profile type you can choose your own template and build your own context to pass to the chosen template.

Hope it helps!